# Find the joint pdf of X and Y for two uniform distributions

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions

Let $X$ have a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,1)$. Given that $X$ = $x$, let $Y$ have a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,x+1)$.

Find the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$. Sketch the region where $f(x,y) > 0$.

Find *f*<sub>Y</sub>$(y)$, the marginal pdf of $Y$. Be sure to include the domain.

I'm not really sure where to start. Is *f*<sub>Y</sub>$(y)$ just $\frac{1}{(x+1)-0}$ since that's the pdf of a uniform distribution? And I have no idea how to find the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ from the information given.

Comment: Write the joint as conditional x marginal; beware, though -- you need to have the limits correct